# Can Neewer 3-in-1 remotes be used to trigger both flash and shutter at the same time?

Tags: wireless-flash

I have 3 in 1 Neewer remotes, one transmitter and 4 receivers. Can I use the receivers to fire the flash and activate the shutter with the transmitter at the same time?   I notice there is a flash and shutter or camera slide on the sides, does this mean all I can do is one or the other?  I have a Neewer 670 flash unit and an El cheapo flash that came in the camera kit.  I would like to use remote shutter and remote flash when pressing the remote transmitter button, not sure if that will happen.  I am afraid to try.

Comment: FC-16 or 240s?  It looks like Neewer labels both of these as "3-in-1" triggers from Amazon's listings.

Comment: I do not know your exact configuration, but I would try to set diferent frequency, one to triger the camera, and after that, the camera triggers the flash.

Comment: Well I added a trigger transmitter to the camera shoe and a receiver with the cable to trigger the shutter on the camera.  Works great.  All I need for two remote flash units is a receiver for each, a receiver for the shutter on the camera and two transmitters, one to send the signal to the flash units from the camera shoe and one to trigger the shutter.  The shutter trigger thusly triggers the flash shoe on the camera and thusly sending a signal to the two receivers on the flash units!!  Easy to do and works great.

Comment: What is your second transmitter set to? My problem is that the neewer fc-16 has to be set to "Camera" to trigger the shutter on the receiver. How do I set my new transmitter so that it activates upon the first transmitter being pressed?

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely unlikely, even if you could get the remote to fire both camera and flash, that they would be in sync.

Remember there is a (small) delay from pressing the shutter button, the only way to reliably sync the flash with the shutter is to have the camera itself trigger the flash(es).

If you did manage to get the remote to fire both, it's highly likely that the flash would fire before the shutter has started to open.

Comment: Thanks for your help,  I figured a way to do it.  I need to add a transmitter to the cameras flash shoe set to flash and use another remote transmitter set to trigger and to signal a receiver that has a cable to the camera to trigger the camera shutter.  That will set off the flash when the camera is triggered.  Just more money! LOL!!

Comment: Actually, the Yongnuo RF-603 (and successor) transceivers can do dual-duty as a shutter Rx/flash Tx with correct timing, so you only need three units, rather than four to do remote shutter and one remote flash. It all depends on the units you use.

Comment: Well I added a trigger transmitter to the camera shoe and a receiver with the cable to trigger the shutter on the camera.  Works great.  All I need for two remote flash units is a receiver for each, a receiver for the shutter on the camera and two transmitters, one to send the signal to the flash units from the camera shoe and one to trigger the shutter.  The shutter trigger thusly triggers the flash shoe on the camera and thusly sending a signal to the two receivers on the flash units!!  Easy to do and works great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll need another transmitter/receiver set on a different radio channel to act as the shutter remote.

Most manual flash radio triggers can also be used as shutter remotes, since the signal to fire the flash and the signal to release the shutter are both simple shorts (i.e. electronically, the signals are identical, it's just whether it's on a flash foot or a cable release port). If you cable a receiver to the camera's cable release port, you can use a transmitter as your in-hand shutter button.

Then put all your flashes on receivers and a second transmitter on the camera's hotshoe. And make sure to set all of the flash radio gear to a different channel from the shutter triggers, so the lights don't fire at the same time as the shutter. If they're triggered simultaneously, the flash burst will be too early for the exposure. The *camera* has to control when the flashes fire.

There are some triggers that can be both the camera shutter receiver and the flash transmitter at the same time, and either use a small delay (Yongnuo RF-603 II / RF-605) or different channels (Flashpoint R2 SPT), automatically, so you'd only have to get an additional transmitter.